# Issues with importing aiplatform into python3

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to run the following sample code from Google APIs,
https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/main/samples/snippets/prediction_service/predict_image_object_detection_sample.py . The goal of the code is to utilize VertexAI endpoints to make predictions.

I have installed the latest version of google, google-cloud and google-cloud-aiplatform using pip3, in this order. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the mentioned packages in the reverse order as well.

On line 18 of the code `from google.cloud import aiplatform` it shows and error saying `ImportError: cannot import name 'aiplatform' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)`.

---

Update: I switched the environment, and it did no good. However, when I tried a Conda environment it worked!

It installed the same version of aiplatform (1.18.2). I'm suspecting there might be some issues with the structure of google.cloud modules in my system. But I'm not sure How should I approach the problem and where exactly to look.

Comment: Do you have a local module of your own named `google.py`, or a subdirectory named `google`?

Comment: Thanks, John for your comment. No, I have no other file or directory named google. Neither in my local directory nor in my path.

Comment: What specific version of google-cloud and google-cloud-aiplatform do you have installed?

Comment: The latest (1.18.2). That shouldn't be the issue. I managed to make it work by switching to a Conda environment. Please read the update. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a new/fresh python virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, didn't work.